# Multiple choice question on continuous function on a unit ball

Tags: metric-spaces, continuity

Pick out true:

Let $B$ be the closed unit ball and $D$ be the open unit ball.

a.Given a continuous function $g:B\rightarrow \mathbb R$ there always exists a continuous function $f:\mathbb R^2\rightarrow \mathbb R$ such  that $f=g$ on  $B$.

b.
Given a continuous function $g:D\rightarrow \mathbb R$ there always exists a continuous function $f:\mathbb R^2\rightarrow \mathbb R$ such  that $f=g$ on  $D$.

c.there always exists a continuous function $f:\mathbb R^2\rightarrow \mathbb R$ such  that $f\equiv 1$ on the set $\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^{2}:x^2+y^2=3/2\}$ and $f\equiv 0$ on the set $B \cup \{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^{2}:x^2+y^2 \geq 2\}$

I dont know where to start.I feel that I have not learnt any theorem which can give me any conclusion on this.I have finished learning metric spaces.

Comment: I think that a is true and b is false. Can you think of examples where these would fail (or be true) if B and D were subsets of R? (Infinite discontinuities?)

Answer (score 0):

a) Find a function $h\colon \mathbb R^2\to B$ that is the identity on $B$ (Hint: scale any point at distance $>1$ down to distance $1$ fro the origin). Then let $f=g\circ h$.

b) Consider $g(x,y)=\frac1{1-x}$

c) Hint: Try to find a continuous function $h\colon[0,\infty)\to \mathbb R$ such that $h(r)=0$ for $0\le r\le 1$ as well as  for $r\ge 2$, whereas $h(\frac32)=1$.